# Make http post with data from observable in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to use data from observables that lives in my `registerStore` service to send them in the body of my http post request. How can I do so?

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '@env/environment';
import { RegisterStore } from './register.store';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class RegisterService {
  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private registerStore: RegisterStore
  ) {}

  signUp() {
    this.httpClient
      .post(
        `${environment.baseAuthUrl}/signup`,
        { email, password }, // <- this should come from registerStore.email$ and registerStore.password$
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you normally get data from an observable?

Comment: subscribing. But is there any other way to make it work beside subscribing? While using Ngrx I never subscribe to use my obs data, I use withLatestFrom instead. But I cannot figure out how to mimic this behaviour without ngrx

Comment: That's not specific to NgRx, it's a general RxJS operator: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom

Comment: I know but I cannot figure out a way to use it here. What is the `source` equivalent I should `pipe` to?

Answer (score 0):

When you use signUp you trigger it, so you need to use the CURRENT STORE STATE VALUES of email and password,
it is unclear what store solution you use but it can be something like:
`registerStore.state.email` which returns the current value and NOT the observable of that value

```js
signUp() {
    this.httpClient
      .post(
        `${environment.baseAuthUrl}/signup`,
        { registerStore.state.email, registerStore.state.password }, // <- this should come from registerStore.email$ and registerStore.password$
      )
```